Get left scroll position of table
I am trying to get the left scroll position of my DT table in shiny.
Here is an example application for how I was attempting to capture it.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js_save_scroll <- '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(settings, json) {
  console.log("Test log");
  $("#tbl").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Table clicked");
    var table = $("#tbl");
    var scrollPos = $("#tbl").scrollLeft();
    console.log("Scroll position: " + scrollPos);
  });
});
'

df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100, ncol = 50))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script(js_save_scroll),
    
    DTOutput('tbl')
    ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(df)
  }
)


When I check the console in my browser, scrollPos is always set to zero.

I think this does what you're looking for.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js_save_scroll <- '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(settings, json) {
  $("#tbl").on("click", function() {
    var scroll_x = $(document).scrollLeft();
    var scroll_y = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log("Scroll position: " + scroll_x + ", " + scroll_y);
  });
});
'

df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100, ncol = 50))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script(js_save_scroll),
    
    DTOutput('tbl')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(df)
  }
)

